# Visual Studio hangs after I change any file in the App_Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-applications, subsonic, asp.net-2.0

I have an issue with my visual studio. It was fine for a long time but now every time I make a change in the App_Code it freezes for some time. I checked the resources and it seems like it is compiling the website automatically. It didn't do that earlier and even if it did the studio would still work fine.

Any thoughts how can I fix this?

Comment: Is it a Web Site project or a Web Application project?

Comment: Website project using Subsonic 2.1 for DAL.

Comment: @DeepakSharma You asked six years ago - did you find a fix? I have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

It could be rebuilding your XML documentation, which can cause larger projects to hang for 10 - 15 seconds while it rebuilds it. If you have any other projects (class libraries, etc.) in your solution that your web project depends on, prevent them from generating the XML documentation file:

1. Right click on project and choose Properties
2. Switch to the Compile page
3. Uncheck the "Generate XML documentation file"

Repeat this for all the projects. If this is not the case then let me know and I'll remove my answer.

Comment: It is a ASP.NET project so it does not have a DEBUG/RELEASE folders. Also when I check out the Build option it does not give me any option to disable XML Documentation Generation and there is no Compile option in the property pages.

Answer (score 0):

There's a similar report on the connect.microsoft.com site. The microsoft solution pointed to a plugin Document!X, but that didn't seem to cover all reported cases. There are a couple of comments (including mine) which states that the problem occurs even without the plugin.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/368690/visual-studio-2008-sp1-ide-temporarily-freezes-when-saving-code-files

Other people in my office have also confirmed that this problem is happening for them. Maybe it's a common plugin we all use. But, I'm hoping there is a setting we can change to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

After changing codes in app_code , Visual studio tries to find refrences to functions .It hangs a few seconds but I found that when system is low on RAM. It hangs and must be closed.